# Index sum and strip my matrix

Tags: code-golf, matrix

### Index sum and strip my matrix

Given a matrix/2d array in your preferable language

**Input:**

- The matrix will always have an odd length
- The matrix will always be perfectly square
- The matrix values can be any integer in your language (positive or negative)

---

**Example:**

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  3  4  5  6  7  8
3  4  50 6  7  8  9
4  5  6 100 8  9  10
5  6  7  8 -9  10 11
6  7  8  9  10 11 12
7  8 900 10 11 12 0
```

---

**Definitions:**

- The "central number" is defined as the number that has the same amount of numbers to the left,right,up and down

**In this case its middlemost 100**

- The "outer shell" is the collection of numbers which their x and y index is or 0 or the matrix size

---

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2                 8
3                 9
4                 10
5                 11
6                 12
7  8 900 10 11 12 0
```

### Your task:

Add to the central number the sum of each row and column after multiplying the values in each by their 1-based index

**A single row for example**

```
4  5  6  7  8
```

**for each number**

```
number * index + number * index.....

4*1 + 5*2 + 6*3 + 7*4 + 8*5 => 100
```

---

**example:**

```
 2 -3 -9  4  7  1  5  => 61
-2  0 -2 -7 -7 -7 -4  => -141
 6 -3 -2 -2 -3  2  1  => -10
 8 -8  4  1 -8  2  0  => -20
-5  6  7 -1  8  4  8  => 144
 1  5  7  8  7 -9 -5  => 10
 7  7 -2  2 -7 -8  0  => -60
                         |
78 65 60 45 -15 -89 10   => 154
                     |
                     => -16
```

- For all rows and columns you combine these values..
- Now you sum these too => 154-16 = 138
- You add that number to the "central number" and remove the "outer shell" of the matrix

---

```
 0 -2 -7 -7 -7     => -88
-3 -2 -2 -3  2     => -15
-8  4 1+138 -8  2  => 395
 6  7 -1  8  4     => 69
 5  7  8  7 -9     => 26

19 69 442 30 -26
```

do this untill you end up with a single number

```
-2 -2 -3     => -15
 4  1060 -8  => 2100
 7 -1  8     => 29

27 2115 5
```

- Add 2114+2147 to 1060
- Remove the "outer shell" and get 5321
- Now we have a single number left

**this is the output!**

test cases:

```
-6

-6
```

---

```
-7 -1  8
-4 -6  7
-3 -6  6

2
```

---

```
 6  7 -2  5  1
-2  6 -4 -2  3
-1 -4  0 -2 -7
 0  1  4 -4  8
-8 -6 -5  0  2

-365
```

---

```
 8  3  5  6  6 -7  5
 6  2  4 -2 -1  8  3
 2  1 -5  3  8  2 -3
 3 -1  0  7 -6  7 -5
 0 -8 -4 -9 -4  2 -8
 8 -9 -3  5  7  8  5
 8 -1  4  5  1 -4  8

17611
```

---

```
-9 -7  2  1  1 -2  3 -7 -3  6  7  1  0
-7 -8 -9 -2  7 -2  5  4  7 -7  8 -9  8
-4  4 -1  0  1  5 -3  7  1 -2 -9  4  8
 4  8  1 -1  0  7  4  6 -9  3 -9  3 -9
-6 -8 -4 -8 -9  2  1  1 -8  8  2  6 -4
-8 -5  1  1  2 -9  3  7  2  5 -6 -1  2
-8 -5 -7 -4 -9 -2  5  0  2 -4  2  0 -2
-3 -6 -3  2 -9  8  1 -5  5  0 -4 -1 -9
-9 -9 -8  0 -5 -7  1 -2  1 -4 -1  5  7
-6 -9  4 -2  8  7 -9 -5  3 -1  1  8  4
-6  6 -3 -4  3  5  6  8 -2  5 -1 -7 -9
-1  7 -9  4  6  7  6 -8  5  1  0 -3  0
-3 -2  5 -4  0  0  0 -1  7  4 -9 -4  2

-28473770
```

### This is a codegolf challenge so the program with the lowest bytecount wins

Comment: you are correct, thats a typo

Comment: why would negative numbers be an issue? I dont think the challenge should adjust for esolangs but maybe the other way around is more appropriate

Comment: @LuisMendo I think it's not a problem, the rule "The matrix values can be any integer in your language" means to me that if your language doesn't have negative numbers, it shouldn't support them.

Comment: actually thats correct. but then the test cases wont work properly

Comment: @Fatalize Actually I hadn't seen that rule :-D Removing comments

Comment: "I dont think the challenge should adjust for esolangs but maybe the other way around is more appropriate" that should be engraved in stone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
tnq?`t&+stn:*sytn2/)+ 7M(6Lt3$)tnq
```

Input is a 2D array with `;` as row separator

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dG5xP2B0JitzdG46KnN5dG4yLykrIDdNKDZMdDMkKXRucQ&input=WzggIDMgIDUgIDYgIDYgLTcgIDU7IDYgIDIgIDQgLTIgLTEgIDggIDM7IDIgIDEgLTUgIDMgIDggIDIgLTM7IDMgLTEgIDAgIDcgLTYgIDcgLTU7IDAgLTggLTQgLTkgLTQgIDIgLTg7IDggLTkgLTMgIDUgIDcgIDggIDU7IDggLTEgIDQgIDUgIDEgLTQgIDhd) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJSBMb29wIHRvIHJlYWQgYWxsIGlucHV0cwp0bnE_YHQmK3N0bjoqc3l0bjIvKSsgN00oNkx0MyQpdG5xICAgICAlIEFjdHVhbCBjb2RlCl1dRFQgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICUgRW5kIGxvb3BzLCBkaXNwbGF5&input=Wy02XQpbLTcgLTEgIDg7IC00IC02ICA3OyAtMyAtNiAgNl0KWzYgIDcgLTIgIDUgIDE7IC0yICA2IC00IC0yICAzOyAtMSAtNCAgMCAtMiAtNzsgMCAgMSAgNCAtNCAgODsgLTggLTYgLTUgIDAgIDJdCls4ICAzICA1ICA2ICA2IC03ICA1OyA2ICAyICA0IC0yIC0xICA4ICAzOyAyICAxIC01ICAzICA4ICAyIC0zOyAzIC0xICAwICA3IC02ICA3IC01OyAwIC04IC00IC05IC00ICAyIC04OyA4IC05IC0zICA1ICA3ICA4ICA1OyA4IC0xICA0ICA1ICAxIC00ICA4XQpbLTkgLTcgIDIgIDEgIDEgLTIgIDMgLTcgLTMgIDYgIDcgIDEgIDA7IC03IC04IC05IC0yICA3IC0yICA1ICA0ICA3IC03ICA4IC05ICA4OyAtNCAgNCAtMSAgMCAgMSAgNSAtMyAgNyAgMSAtMiAtOSAgNCAgODsgIDQgIDggIDEgLTEgIDAgIDcgIDQgIDYgLTkgIDMgLTkgIDMgLTk7IC02IC04IC00IC04IC05ICAyICAxICAxIC04ICA4ICAyICA2IC00OyAtOCAtNSAgMSAgMSAgMiAtOSAgMyAgNyAgMiAgNSAtNiAtMSAgMjsgLTggLTUgLTcgLTQgLTkgLTIgIDUgIDAgIDIgLTQgIDIgIDAgLTI7IC0zIC02IC0zICAyIC05ICA4ICAxIC01ICA1ICAwIC00IC0xIC05OyAtOSAtOSAtOCAgMCAtNSAtNyAgMSAtMiAgMSAtNCAtMSAgNSAgNzsgLTYgLTkgIDQgLTIgIDggIDcgLTkgLTUgIDMgLTEgIDEgIDggIDQ7IC02ICA2IC0zIC00ICAzICA1ICA2ICA4IC0yICA1IC0xIC03IC05OyAtMSAgNyAtOSAgNCAgNiAgNyAgNiAtOCAgNSAgMSAgMCAtMyAgMDsgLTMgLTIgIDUgLTQgIDAgIDAgIDAgLTEgIDcgIDQgLTkgLTQgIDJdCgoKCg).

#### Explanation

```
tnq       % Take input. Duplicate, get number of elements, subtract 1
?         % If greater than 0
  `       %   Do...while
    t     %     Duplicate
    &+    %     Sum matrix with its transpose
    s     %     Sum each column. Gives a row vector
    tn:   %     Vector [1 2 ...] with the same size
    *     %     Multiply element-wise
    s     %     Sum of vector. This will be added to center entry of the matrix
    y     %     Duplicate matrix
    tn2/  %     Duplicate, get half its number of elements. Gives non-integer value
    )     %     Get center entry of the matrix, using linear index with implicit rounding
    +     %     Add center entry to sum of previous vector
    7M    %     Push index of center entry again
    (     %     Assgined new value to center of the matrix
    6Lt   %     Array [2 j1-1], twice. This will be used to remove shell
    3$)   %     Apply row and col indices to remove outer shell of the matrix
    tnq   %     Duplicate, number of elements, subtract 1. Falsy if matrix has 1 entry
          %   End do...while implicitly. The loop is exited when matrix has 1 entry
          % End if implicitly
          % Display stack implicitly
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7, 229 bytes

This is my first attempt at something like this, so hopefully I followed all the rules with this submission. This is just a function which takes in a list of lists as its parameter. I feel like the sums and list comprehension could probably be shortened a little bit, but it was too hard for me. :D

```
def r(M):
  t=len(M)
  if t==1:return M[0][0]
  M[t/2][t/2]+=sum(a*b for k in [[l[x] for l in M]for x in range(0,t)]for a,b in enumerate(k,1))+sum([i*j for l in M for i,j in enumerate(l,1)])
  return r([p[+1:-1]for p in M[1:-1]])
```

Thx to Easterly Irk for helping me shave off a few bytes.

Comment: You can remove a couple spaces between operators (`...) + sum([i*j...` -> `...)+sum([i*j...`), but overall, great first post!!!!

Comment: oooh missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `...]for ...` works. You can remove at least 2 space like that. (end of list hits the for loop)

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 257 bytes

here is a **non** esolang answer

```
void f(int[][]p){while(p.Length>1){int a=p.Length;int r=0;for(int i=0;i<a;i++)for(int j=0;j<a;j++)r+=(i+j+2)*p[i][j];p[a/2][a/2]+=r;p=p.Where((i,n)=>n>0&&n<p.Length-1).Select(k=>k.Where((i,n)=>n>0&&n<p.Length-1).ToArray()).ToArray();}Console.Write(p[0][0]);
```

ungolfed:

```
void f(int[][]p)
    {
        while (p.Length>1)
        {
            int a=p.Length;
            int r=0; //integer for number to add to middle
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
                    r +=(i+j+2)*p[i][j]; //add each element to counter according to their 1 based index
            p[a / 2][a / 2] += r; //add counter to middle
            p = p.Where((i, n) => n > 0 && n < p.Length - 1).Select(k => k.Where((i, n) => n > 0 && n < p.Length - 1).ToArray()).ToArray(); //strip outer shell from array
        }
        Console.Write(p[0][0]); //print last and only value in array
    }
```

Comment: Hey now, J isn't an esolang.

Comment: This doesn't compile if you don't include `using System.Linq` and `using System`. I'm not sure if it's required by the rules though.

Comment: its not a full program, its only a function so its ok as far as i know.

i mean, would i also need to include the App.config and all the bytes in the properties and makefile? no

Comment: @downrep_nation It's just weird, since I've seen some people include them in the source when it has only been a function and they've included the bytes on the score.

Comment: Now when I think about it, I'm on the line that you should import atleast `System.Linq`. Other languages that require importing in order to use certain features go through the same process, so I think it's unfair to assume that every module is loaded to memory in C#.

Comment: @TuukkaX System.Linq is absolutely default in c# 5. Im not implying Console is statically define so i just Write() or something like that right

Comment: @downrep_nation I see. If you're using C# 5+ features then edit the title to say something like `C# 5+` or `C# 5`.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 66 bytes

```
([:}:@}."1@}:@}.]+(i.@,~=](]+*)<.@-:)@#*[:+/^:2#\*]+|:)^:(<.@-:@#)
```

Straight-forward approach based on the process described in the challenge.

`[:+/^:2#\*]+|:` gets the sum. `]+(i.@,~=](]+*)<.@-:)@#*` is a particularly ugly way to increment the center by the sum. `[:}:@}."1@}:@}.` removes the outer shell. There probably is a better way to do this.

### Usage

```
   f =: ([:}:@}."1@}:@}.]+(i.@,~=](]+*)<.@-:)@#*[:+/^:2#\*]+|:)^:(<.@-:@#)
   f _6
_6
   f _7 _1 8 , _4 _6 7 ,: _3 _6 6
2
   f 6 7 _2 5 1 , _2 6 _4 _2 3 , _1 _4 0 _2 _7 , 0 1 4 _4 8 ,: _8 _6 _5 0 2 
_365
   f 8 3 5 6 6 _7 5 , 6 2 4 _2 _1 8 3 , 2 1 _5 3 8 2 _3 , 3 _1 0 7 _6 7 _5 , 0 _8 _4 _9 _4 2 _8 ,8 _9 _3 5 7 8 5 ,: 8 _1 4 5 1 _4 8
17611
   f (13 13 $ _9 _7 2 1 1 _2 3 _7 _3 6 7 1 0 _7 _8 _9 _2 7 _2 5 4 7 _7 8 _9 8 _4 4 _1 0 1 5 _3 7 1 _2 _9 4 8 4 8 1 _1 0 7 4 6 _9 3 _9 3 _9 _6 _8 _4 _8 _9 2 1 1 _8 8 2 6 _4 _8 _5 1 1 2 _9 3 7 2 5 _6 _1 2 _8 _5 _7 _4 _9 _2 5 0 2 _4 2 0 _2 _3 _6 _3 2 _9 8 1 _5 5 0 _4 _1 _9 _9 _9 _8 0 _5 _7 1 _2 1 _4 _1 5 7 _6 _9 4 _2 8 7 _9 _5 3 _1 1 8 4 _6 6 _3 _4 3 5 6 8 _2 5 _1 _7 _9 _1 7 _9 4 6 7 6 _8 5 1 0 _3 0 _3 _2 5 _4 0 0 0 _1 7 4 _9 _4 2)
_28473770
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 114 bytes

```
{l1,?hh.|:{:Im:I:?:{[L:I:M]h:JmN,Ll:2/D(IJ,M{$\:?c:{:{:ImN,I:1+:N*.}f+.}a+.}:N+.;'(DIJ),N.)}f.}f:7a$\:7a&.}.
brbr.
```

I'm suprised this even works to be honest. At least I realized that Brachylog really needs a "change value of that element" as a built-in though…

Usage example:

```
?- run_from_file('code.brachylog', '[[0:_2:_7:_7:_7]:[_3:_2:_2:_3:2]:[_8:4:139:_8:2]:[6:7:_1:8:4]:[5:7:8:7:_9]]', Z).
Z = 5321 .
```

#### Explanation

More readable (and longer) version:

```
{l1,?hh.|:2f:7a$\:7a&.}.
:Im:I:?:3f.
[L:I:M]h:JmN,Ll:2/D(IJ,M:4&:N+.;'(DIJ),N.)
$\:?c:5a+.
:6f+.
:ImN,I:1+:N*.
brbr.
```

I'm just gonna explain roughly what each predicate (i.e each line except the first one which is Main Predicate + predicate 1) does:

- Main predicate + predicate 1 `{l1,?hh.|:2f:7a$\:7a&.}.` : If the input has only one row, then end the algorithm and return the only value. Else find all rows which satisfy predicate 2, then apply predicate 7 on the resulting matrix, then predicate 7 on the transposition, then call recursively.
- Predicate 2 `:Im:I:?:3f.` :Take the `I`th row of the matrix, find all values of that row which satisfy predicate 3 with `I` and the matrix as additional inputs.
- Predicate 3 `[L:I:M]h:JmN,Ll:2/D(IJ,M:4&:N+.;'(DIJ),N.)` : `L` is the row, `I` is the index of the row, `M` is the matrix. `N` is the `J`th element of `L`. If the length of `L` divided by 2 is equal to both `I` and `J`, then the output is the sum of `N` with the result of predicate 4 on the matrix. Otherwise the output is just `N`. This predicate essentialy recreates the matrix with the exception that the center element gets added to the sum.
- Predicate 4 `$\:?c:5a+.` : Apply predicate 5 on each row and column of the matrix, unify the output with the sum of the results.
- Predicate 5 `:6f+.` : Find all valid outputs of predicate 6 on the row, unify the output with the sum of the resulting list.
- Predicate 6 `:ImN,I:1+:N*.` : `N` is the `I`th value of the row, unify the output with `N * (I+1)`.
- Predicate 7 `brbr.` : Remove the first and last row of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 56 chars

```
{{1 1↓¯1 ¯1↓⍵+(-⍴⍵)↑(⌈.5×⍴⍵)↑+/(⍵⍪⍉⍵)+.×⍳≢⍵}⍣(⌊.5×≢⍵)⊣⍵}
```

In English:

- `⍣(⌊.5×≢⍵)` repeat "half the size of a dimension rounded"-times
- `(⍵⍪⍉⍵)+.×⍳≢⍵` inner product of the matrix and its transpose with the index vector
- `(-⍴⍵)↑(⌈.5×⍴⍵)↑` transform result in matrix padded with 0s
- `1 1↓¯1 ¯1↓` removes outer shell